# Hibernate criteria query for ((C1 and C2) or C3) and C4

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
        Predicate C= cb.conjunction();
        C.getExpressions().add(C1);
        C.getExpressions().add(C2)
        Predicate orCondition = cb.disjunction();
        orCondition.getExpressions().add(C3);
        orCondition.getExpressions().add(C);
        C4.getExpressions().add(orCondition);
```

But it is not working as expected.

I have tried with Criterion also,but it is could not add Criterion to hibernate Expressions.
Also it is deprecated API.So,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to think "outside in": `.and(.or(.and(c1, c2), c3), c4)`.

Comment: When I see the SQL logs for this ,it comes as (C1 and C2 or C3) and C4.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, `and` takes precedence over `or`, so parens aren't needed: `C1 and C2 or C3` is the same as `(C1 and C2) or C3` (just like `1 * 2 + 3` is the same as `(1 * 2) + 3`). We usually like putting parens to please our human eyes, but they aren't actually needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it rather be something like

```
Predicate innerAnd = cb.conjunction();
innerAnd.getExpressions().add(C1);
innerAnd.getExpressions().add(C2);

Predicate or = cb.disjunction();
or.getExpressions().add(innerAnd);
or.getExpressions().add(C3);

Predicate outerAnd = cb.conjunction();
outerAnd.getExpressions().add(or);
outerAnd.getExpressions().add(C4);
```

Your code rather leads to something like

```
C1 and C2 and C3
```

and I don't see `C4` in your example.

Comment: Yes,I have written in same manner.When I see the SQL logs it comes as (C1 and C2 or C3) and C4.

Comment: So it should be fine as "and" has a precedence over "or"